# What is the difference "copy" and "save as" document in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word

What will happen to document when we use "copy and paste" document to new one and when we just   use "Save As" in existing document and then creating a new document from existing one?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read this correctly, there is no difference, both will generate a new document without effecting the existing one. Some people might prefer copy+paste so that they do not accidentally hit 'save' on the preexisting document and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big difference but just a minor one because Save as will first save the changes which has been made and then copy data to new document whereas copy and paste will just save the last saved data into new document hence if any changes were made,those changes would not be saved